# Converting Excel formula into JavaScript format

Tags: jquery, math

I'm trying to convert an Excel formula into jQuery.

Excel Formula:`a1 * (a2/ 12) / (1 - (1 + (a2/ 12)) ^ -(a3* 12));`

However, I'm stuck where the operator "^" came out. I researched Math.pow but I'm not sure how I'm gonna set values inside that method

So far, I have this

```
 var temp = $('#slider1').slider('value'); //value is 16000
 var temp2 = $('#slider2').slider('value'); //value is 7
 var temp3 = 3.85;
finalval = Math.pow(temp * (temp3 / 12) / (1 - (1 + (temp3 / 12))), -(temp2 * 12));
 $('#output').text(finalval);
```

I'm not really familiar with Math functions, can

Comment: [Math.pow(base, exponent)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)

Comment: Instead of trying to have everything in one calculations, it makes it easier to keep track of everything if you have several intermediate calculations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_math.asp), but I'm pretty sure your issue is the location of your `Math.pow()`

Maybe try:
`final = Math.pow(amount * (temp / 12) / (1 - (1 + (temp / 12))), -(temp2 * 12))`

Also, you were missing a parenthesis

**Update**
After further review of the calculation (and reviewing comments), I'm pretty sure there's an error in the way we interpreted the calculation. [See this page](http://www.financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html)

The formula should be as follows:

```
    var amount = 16000; //Currency amount of a loan
    var interest = 0.0325; //Percent of interest per period in decimal form
    var years = 7; //Number of periods, this will be elongated into months in the equation.
                   //Time should be in similar units in equation.
    temp1 = amount * (interest / 12) / (1 - Math.pow(1 + (interest / 12), -(years * 12)));
```

Then you can apply the value to your text (according to the JSFiddle provided) using:

```
    $('#monthly').text(Math.round(temp1))
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and check it with the latest fiddle, it wasn't returning the correct value.

Let's have an assumption, where amount=16000, interest = 3.25, years = 7. I'm getting value of 43333, it should be 2132. Do you think the format of the translated formula is the cause?

Comment: Is your interest rate in decimal form? Try 0.0325 instead?

Comment: I just plugged in the values you provided (16,000; 0.0325 {3.25%}; and 7 years) and got a value of $213.22 per month. This seems accurate to me as it results in a total of $17,910.48 over the length of the term. Usually these type of equations require percentages to be in decimal form and not the "whole number" form. I'll adjust my answer to include the variables here and comment the purpose of each variable.

Comment: Converting 3.25 into 0.0325 fixed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Excel, Math.pow is a function who gets two arguments - the base and the exponent:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_pow.asp

Your problematic line should look like this:

```
 final = Math.pow(amount * (temp / 12) / (1 - (1 + (temp / 12))), -(temp2 * 12));
```

Comment: Now I'm having trouble with datatypes. Which variable is perfect to use together with Math.pow for displaying whole numbers?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. Can you give some more information?

Comment: Hi Dekel, thanks for quick response. variable final returns a value 4.484155085839392e-188, I think I'm not getting the right output and format. I want to display it as a whole number

Comment: Can you also let us know the values of amount/temp/temp2? What are the expected values?

Comment: Without the values for temp and temp2 it's impossible to help. You can add a comment inside your code for the values you check with.

Comment: You could try converting to an integer (aka whole number) or use the `Math.round()` function. See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Comment: Thank you for adding the jsfiddle link. I was able to review your issue much easier. Hopefully I solved your problem